# Parsing date from .csv filename into a new column for multiple .csv files using Windows PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a series of data files that contain data for a given day and are titled as such: "Aug 27, 2019 Measurement Log.csv"

The timestamp data within these files only contains the time, not the date. For each file (there are several hundred) I would like to capture the date from the title and populate the first column with the appropriate value. The output .csv file would have a "Date" column with "8/27/2019" populated in each cell (but only for as many rows as there are data points).

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions you can provide!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Code will not be written from scratch for you. You should be looking into import-csv, export-csv and get-date.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you need but hopefully should point you in the right direction. All it does is loop through the files and grabs the date from the name and then grabs the CSV data and adds a new member to the output. You might need add a Select-Object in the mix if you want it to be the date to be the first column.

```
$results = Get-ChildItems -FIlter .csv | % {
    $d = Get-Date $_.Name.Substring(0,12) -Format 'M/d/yyyy' 
    Import-Csv $_.Name -Delimiter ',' | % {
        $_ | Add-Member -Name Date -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $d -PassThru
    }
}

$results
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to iterate over the csv files in the folder that have names beginning what looks like a date in format 'MMM d, yyyy'.
Next, try and parse that part of the filename into a DateTime object and add this date as new first column in the file.

Something like

```
# get a datetime object to use in [datetime]::TryParseExact()
$date = Get-Date

# get the csv files with a name that matches the date format 'MMM d, yyyy'
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -Filter '*.csv' -File | 
    Where-Object { $_.BaseName -match '^([a-z]{3}\s+\d{1,2},\s+\d{4})'} |
    ForEach-Object {
        # parse the date from the file name as captured in $matches[1]
        if ([datetime]::TryParseExact($matches[1], 'MMM d, yyyy', [cultureinfo]'en-US', 'None', [ref]$date)) {
            (Import-Csv -Path $_.FullName) | 
             Select-Object @{Name = 'Date'; Expression = {'{0:M\/d\/yyyy}' -f $date}}, * |
             Export-Csv -Path $_.FullName -NoTypeInformation
        }
    }
```

Regex details:

```
^                 Assert position at the beginning of the string
(                 Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [a-z]          Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” (case insensitive)
      {3}         Exactly 3 times
   \s             Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \d             Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
      {1,2}       Between one and 2 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   ,              Match the character “,” literally
   \s             Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
      +           Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \d             Match a single character that is a “digit” (any decimal number in any Unicode script)
      {4}         Exactly 4 times
)
```